# Application specific linux system tuning

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, ram

I'm running an application under wine (Navico insight map creator) on multiple machines and am in the process of benchmarking and optimizing the performance of this process.

I find the following interwsting.
Windows:
Application set to unlimitrd cache takes 25% of the time that using no cache / decache unused does.
While using unlimited cache, it seem a to use a bit more CPU, about 30% load on an 8 core and (fx-8150) with ram at 2133mhz

But under Linux, CPU is maxed out (according to system monitor) on dual e5-2697 v2's in an dell R720
With no change in processing time between cache settings.

So, I'm trying to figure out how i can find the bottlenecks in the Linux system and if the system monitor is actually reporting CPU usage properly or if there is an I/o bottleneck somewhere. Ram is too slow? Or maybe its just an issue with running under wine?

I'm currently in the process of running the same exact data through this application and timing it with the various systems to have an equal comparison of performance.

Any information regarding identifying bottlenecks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific on how you are setting the cache size on Windows and Linux / Wine.  It could be that Wine is ignoring requests to set the (windows) cache size.  On native Linux the OS caches recently used files, etc by default using RAM that is not used for other things.  You flush the page cache, by directly controlling how much memory is available for caching is difficult ... and not normally done.

Comment: The cache setting is within the application and not at the system level. System caches are left at defaults.

Comment: So how does this application cache actually work?  It could be that the cache is ineffective on Wine/Linux because the file is already being cached by the Linux OS.

Comment: Its a georeferenced image retiling & conversion software. So, it either keeps lots f spurxe imagery in memory or detaches what its not currently working on.

Comment: Hmm ... so not caching files from the file system.  Well it could simply be that the software can effectively make use of 2 cores but not 8 cores.  Bear in mind that Wine on Linux is not a good option if your primary goal is performance.  You would be better off running the application natively on Linux if that is possible.  Or ... maybe find another application that runs natively on Linux.

Comment: The 2 CPU system has 40+ cores and they run at 100%. Unfortunately this application is a windows only application that I would like to wrap with a bunch automation and job queue software. So I would like to make the best of this on a Linux system for scalability and windows licensing purposes.

Comment: Anyway, I think maybe you would be better off asking this on serverfault.  Its not really a programming question.